# .htaccess rewriting to a different folder where it contains css/js

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have re-written in my .htaccess file in the following way. where I need to direct to games/mybeautifulgame/index.php pages when the user directs to /game?mygame

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   [sitename.com]/game?mygame [sitename.com]/games/mybeautifulgame/index.php
```

However all my bootstrap related CSS, js are inside games/mybeautifullgame folder
example: 
games/mybeautifullgame/css/filename.css
games/mybeautifullgame/js/filename.js

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use %{QUERY_STRING} to capture the query string data, otherwise `?` just means optional for the previous character.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mygame$
RewriteRule [sitename.com]/game [sitename.com]/games/mybeautifulgame/index.php
```

Regarding the CSS and js files, you could use absolute paths (just add `/` at the beginning of the URL).

Comment: I'm typing => https://www.example.com/?game=mygame 
Need to show here = > https://www.example.com/games/mybeautifulgame/index.php


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mygame$
RewriteRule https://www.example.com/game https://www.example.com/games/mybeautifulgame/index.php

Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: @coding_lover your original question was /game?mygame but if you want /?game=mygame, use this: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^game=mygame$